# May i render the react-portal inside my react application?

Tags: reactjs, portal

I use react 16. I want to render portal inside my app like that:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root">
      <div>...My app stuff</div>
      <div id="modal-root">... portal stuff</div> <-- portal content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But official doc recommends render portal next to, not in app.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root"></div>
    <div id="modal-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it the only correct way to use the portal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of portal is that you can render it anywhere in the DOM tree, all you need is a valid DOM Node to render it into, its not necessary for it to be next to `app-root`

**According to the Docs**

> However, sometimes it’s useful to insert a child into a different
>   location in the DOM:
>
> ```
> render() {
>   // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
>   // domNode is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
>   return ReactDOM.createPortal(
>     this.props.children,
>     domNode,
>   );
> }
> ```